# Connecting to the unofficial Snapchat API

Tags: snapchat

I have looked for some of the unofficial Snapchat APIs (since there's no official one yet) and tried to use them, but I got an error every time (mostly it's 404 Page not found).
Does anybody have/work with a valid Sanpchat API?
Thanks

Comment: It would help if you told us which language(s) you are planning to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find how to get SnapChatAPI

https://www.npmjs.com/package/snapchat